# How to combine three Date/time variables into one?

Tags: r, time-series, hazard

I'm applying a Cox-hazard model and i need some help on the time variable. 
Let's say the context is reservations of a hotel room. 
In my df, i have 3 date/time columns: 
- Reservation date
- Arrival date
- Event date (date which represents the event im interested in: extra service booking or whatever) with **Reservation date < Event date < Arrival date**.

Since all rows represent individuals, every row has its own reservation date, arrival date and event date. Naturally sometimes some rows have the same values when it comes to these variables. 
Therefore i created two new time variables which is a combination of the default 3:
- One which represents (Arrival date - event date)
- The other which represents (Event date - Reservation date).

Now i want to create a time/date variable which includes all three of the date variables such that:
- the minimum value is the reservation date
- the maximum value is the arrival date
- both related to the event date.

Am I overthinking some simple formula/recoding?

Thanks in advance:)